# onclick operation not working in phonegap for FileAPI

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap-plugins

```
    <html>
      <head>
        <title>FileWriter Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
funtion init()
{
      document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
 }   
        function onDeviceReady() {
            window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
        }
           function gotFS(fileSystem) {
            fileSystem.root.getFile("readme.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileEntry, fail);
        }

        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, fail);
            fileEntry.createWriter(win, fail);
            fileEntry.file(gotFile, fail);

        }

        function gotFileWriter(writer) {
            writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                writer.truncate(100);  
                writer.onwriteend = function(evt) {
                    writer.seek(4);
                    writer.write(" different text +");
                    writer.onwriteend = function(evt){
                        writer.write("contents of file now 'sihesh'");

                    }
                };
            };
            }
        function gotFile(file){
                   readAsText(file);
        }

          function readAsText(file) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
                alert("Read as text");
                alert(evt.target.result);
            };
            reader.readAsText(file);
            alert("success");
        }
    function win(writer) {
        writer.onwrite = function(evt) {
            console.log("write success");
        };
        writer.seek(writer.length);
        writer.write("appended text");
        alert("Append hogya na baa");
    };

    var fail = function(evt) {
        console.log(error.code);
    };
        function fail(evt) {
            console.log(evt.target.error.code);
        }
        function fail(error) {
            console.log(error.code);
        }

        </script>
      </head>
      <body onload="init()">
        <input type="button" id="b1" value="Write" onClick="gotFileWriter()"/><br>
        <input type="button" id="b2" value="Read" onClick="readAsText()" /><br>
        <input type="button" id="b3" value="Append"/><br>
        <input type="button" id="b4" value="Delete"/><br>

        <p>Write File</p>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Basically what i want is on clicking on write button it should write the content in file and on click of read button it should retrieve and display it but what happens is because of device ready the functions gets automatically called one after other so there is no use of giving on click method on buttons but what i want is onclick of write button it should write and on click of read button it should read .
So please anybody help me to sort out my problem.  :(
**Note:when i pass gotFileWriter() method(without device ready) on click for writer it gives following error.  09-30 00:16:10.112: E/Web Console(829): TypeError: Result of expression 'file' [undefined] is not an object. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-1.9.0.js:2404**

Comment: where did `init` method declare? Why is there `fail` function defination

Comment: i have made changes to code sir .please go through the code again :)

Comment: Why is there three `fail` function defination

Comment: `onload="init()"` is unnecessary, so remove `funtion init()` from code. `document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);` is enough

Comment: update version of cordova to atleast 3.5.1. Because, google store demand this requirement

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem . Below is my code

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>FileWriter Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-1.9.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var file;
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, gotFS, fail);
    }

    function gotFS(fileSystem) {
        file=fileSystem;
        document.querySelector("#b1").addEventListener("click",read1);
        document.querySelector("#b2").addEventListener("click",write1);
        document.querySelector("#b3").addEventListener("click",append1);
        document.querySelector("#b4").addEventListener("click",delete1);

    }

    function read1()
    {
    file.root.getFile("mca3b.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, readAsText, fail);
    }
    function write1()
    {
    file.root.getFile("mca3b.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, gotFileWriter, fail);
    }
     function append1()
    {
    file.root.getFile("mca3b.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, win, fail1);
    }
    function delete1()
    {
    file.root.getFile("mca3b.txt", {create: true, exclusive: false}, del_success, del_fail);

    }

     function gotFileWriter(writer) {
     var mm=document.getElementById("t1").value;
     writer.createWriter(function(cc)
     {
     cc.onwrite=function()
     {
     alert("Done writing");
     }
     cc.write(mm);
     });
    alert("WRiterrrrr"); 
     }


      function readAsText(file) {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
            alert("Read as text");
            alert(evt.target.result);
        };
        reader.readAsText(file);
        alert("success");
    }
function win(writer) {
 writer.createWriter(function(cc)
     {
     cc.onwrite=function()
     {
     alert("Done writing");
     }
      cc.seek(cc.length);
     cc.write("This is appended text");
     });
    alert("WRiterrrrr"); 


    alert("Append hogya na baa");
};

    var fail = function(evt)
     {
    console.log(error.code);
        };

    function fail(evt) {
        console.log(evt.target.error.code);
    }
    function fail1(error) {
        console.log(error.code);
    }

function del_success(entry) {
entry.remove(success20,fail20);
}
function success20()
{
    alert("Removal succeeded");

}
function fail20()
{
alert("Error while deleting file");
}

function del_fail(error) {
    alert('Error removing file: ' + error.code);
}
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
 <center><h1>MCA3B</h1></center>  
 <p>Read,Write ,Append and Delete of File</p>
 <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Some Text" id="t1"/><br>
 <input type="button" id="b2" value="Write"/><br>
 <input type="button" id="b1" value="Read"/><br>
 <input type="button" id="b3" value="Append"/><br>
 <input type="button" id="b4" value="Delete"/>
  </body>
</html>
```